# how to group id and inline the dates using php

Tags: php, mysql, loops

This is my sample code, i want to group id and inline the dates as shown on the image below

```
 $sql_e = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM tbl_attendees");
 while($sql_e_res = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_e)){
    echo'<tr>
    <td>'.$sql_e_res['s_usn'].'</td>
    <td>'.$sql_e_res['s_name'].'</td>
    ';
    $dt = ''.$sql_e_res['at_date'].'';
    $dt = strtotime(str_replace(',', '', $dt));
    $d = date('j',$dt);

    $currentdays = intval(date("t"));
    $i = 0;
    while ($i++ < $currentdays){
        if($i == $d){
            $ff='<td style="text-align:center">'.$d.'</td>';            
        }else{
            $ff='<td style="text-align:center">';
        }
            echo $ff;
    }
        echo'</tr>';                                                    
    }
```

[image: Original]

[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvjyA.png)

Comment: You're gonna need to give us more than a title and some code.

Comment: sorry im new here

Comment: i dont know the term for that , but i just wanna now if it is possible to inline data's(date) by grouping it ids

Comment: just use group by `SELECT * FROM tbl_attendees group by id;` !

Comment: do you need the Maria row for example  to be shown only at 1 row in the table ?

Comment: Just need to change `SELECT * FROM tbl_attendees` to `SELECT * FROM tbl_attendees order by s_usn asc, at_date asc` I think.  Since you don't have an order by the IDs and dates can come in any order when I think you want all the IDs sorted together and all the dates sorted together.  now weather you sort by `s_usn` or `s_name` is up to you.

Comment: @Accountantم why `group by` and not `order by`?  I see no aggregation for which `group by` would be involved.

Comment: @xQbert he said he needs to "merge" , So I thought he might be needing to see every id only in 1 row , not to aggregate the same Ids together.

Comment: @xQbert that was before he edits the question

Comment: when i use group by 3 and 10 will only be showned what about 4,7, 10

Comment: as I understand the tbl_Attendees table I see 3 fields (s_usn,s_name, at_date) given this I assume there are multiple records for a single user representing different attendance dates.  so user 2222 has 3 attendance dates, 3,4 and 7 while ID 1234 has dates of 10 and 12.   By ordering first by ID and then by date based on the existing code all of users 1234 dates (10,12 will get processed in the 2nd while loop, while all of users 2222 dates (3,4,7) would also get processed in the 2nd while loop, causing all users dates to appear before new html rows are generated.  but maybe I'm misreading it.

Comment: if a PHP knowledgeable developer is around, I think all this needs is some breaking logic on the s_usn so new HTML rows are only generated when the ID's change.  that way the result sets get combined.  this could be done in SQL using case statements but I really don't think it's the right answer here as presentation should be handled in the presentation layer, not the data layer.

Comment: I will make it for you when I go home, just give me 30 mints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As xQbert said , you need to sort your query by `s_usn`

EDIT: the query that my code expects to work on is `"SELECT * FROM tbl_attendees ORDER BY s_usn asc;"`

---

I guess this code has a chance to be more optimized but I tried to keep my coding style very close to yours and reusing your var names. I also tried to make the code readability a priority. try this code, and I almost commented everything

the code is a about a big loop throw the result rows, and for every row you are going to check if this is a new student or not. if it is a new student , then you are going to build the attendees days of the previous student in a string named `$daysTDs` looks something like this `"<td>1<td><td><td><td>3<td>...."`

we are going to build this string from an array called `$attendees` that holds all the days this student has attended in it, it may be look something like this

```
  $attendees = [12,10]
```

when we encounter a new student we are going to echo the `$daysTDs` of the previous student and close the row by `</tr>` after the loop is finished we are going also to echo the last student `$daysTDs` string and close it's row by `</tr>`

```
$lastId = "";  //var to check the new students
$daysTDs = ""; // a string holding the TDs of the student e.g '<td>1<td><td><td><td>3<td>....'
$attendees = []; //array to hold the days 
$currentdays = intval(date("t"));

//start query result loop
 while($sql_e_res = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_e)){
    if($sql_e_res['s_usn']!=$lastId){//if new student
        $i = 0;
        //new student ? then build the $daysTDs string from $attendees attay for the previous student
        while ($i++ < $currentdays){ //fot the first student it will be empty and will not get echoed
            if(in_array($i, $attendees)){$daysTDs .= "<td>$i</td>";}
            else{$daysTDs .= "<td></td>";}
        }
        if($lastId!=""){
            echo $daysTDs;//if not first student append the $daysTDs
            echo'</tr>'; //if not first student, then close the row </tr>       
        }
        $attendees = []; // flush the array for the next student
        $daysTDs=""; // empty the TDs string for the next student
        echo'<tr>
        <td>'.$sql_e_res['s_usn'].'</td>
        <td>'.$sql_e_res['s_name'].'</td>';
    }
    $lastId=$sql_e_res['s_usn'];

    $dt = ''.$sql_e_res['at_date'].'';
    $dt = strtotime(str_replace(',', '', $dt));
    $d = date('j',$dt);
    $attendees[]=$d; //push that day to this student attendees array                                               
}
//after the loop is ended finish the last student row
$i=0;
while ($i++ < $currentdays){
    if(in_array($i, $attendees)){$daysTDs .= "<td>$i</td>";}
    else{$daysTDs .= "<td></td>";}
}
echo $daysTDs;
echo'</tr>';
```

check the code and tell me did it get the desired result or not

Comment: wow thank you,wow thank youwow thank youwow thank youwow thank youwow thank youwow thank youwow thank you, this solve my problem, you and xQbert save my life,. now i can finish my thesis project !

Comment: hello, please help me again in my code i want to change legends depending on the values on the database(at_remarks) i cant get it to work... ill provide a link for images http://imgur.com/a/zm85i

Comment: @Anonymouse I'm not sure what exactly do you want, can you reuse the early [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvjyA.png) again so I can understand what do you want to change ?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/bcdMY i want the output to be like this,  legends P=0 ,T=2,E=3,7=U something like that depending on the at_remark column in the table in the database

Comment: imgur.com/a/bcdMY i want the output to be like this, legends P=0 ,T=2,E=3,7=U something like that depending on the at_remark column in the table in the database

Comment: help pls help pls

Comment: @Anonymouse I still don't understand what exactly do you need ! the query result only contains id, name , and days , how do I know that student1 is P or T or U ? , where do these values come from ?

Comment: Its from the attendance of each student, some may enter late, or absent, or can be excused or unexcused dpending on the instructor, so i put another column called at_remarks to determine it for each day but its ok now , i somewhat solve this problem, ehe,thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_attendees
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_attendees order by s_usn asc, at_date asc
```

or use `s_name asc` instead of `s_usn asc` depending if you want the results displayed in order of ID or in order of name.

The control break logic you're using creates a new html row when all the dates for a given id have been processed.  However, because your IDs and dates are not in any order, you're breaking out of the logic too soon due to lack of order on the results set.  You ideally would want the IDs ordered together followed by the dates ordered together so they are processed in sequence.  This is accomplished though an `order by` as illustrated above.

If you have to do it at the database layer.... (but I don't recommend it)

```
SELECT s_usn, s_name, 
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=1 then 'X' end) as 1,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=2 then 'X' end) as 2,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=3 then 'X' end) as 3,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=4 then 'X' end) as 4,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=5 then 'X' end) as 5,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=6 then 'X' end) as 6,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=7 then 'X' end) as 7,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=8 then 'X' end) as 8,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=9 then 'X' end) as 9,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=10 then 'X' end) as 10,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=11 then 'X' end) as 11,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=12 then 'X' end) as 12,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=13 then 'X' end) as 13,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=14 then 'X' end) as 14,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=15 then 'X' end) as 15,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=16 then 'X' end) as 16,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=17 then 'X' end) as 17,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=18 then 'X' end) as 18,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=19 then 'X' end) as 19,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=20 then 'X' end) as 20,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=21 then 'X' end) as 21,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=22 then 'X' end) as 22,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=23 then 'X' end) as 23,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=24 then 'X' end) as 24,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=25 then 'X' end) as 25,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=26 then 'X' end) as 26,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=27 then 'X' end) as 27,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=28 then 'X' end) as 28,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=29 then 'X' end) as 29,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=30 then 'X' end) as 30,
    max(case when extract(day from at_date)=31 then 'X' end) as 31
FROM tbl_Attendees
WHERE extract(month from at_date) = 11 --set up a variable 
      extract(year from at_date)  = 2016 --setup as variable 
GROUP BY S_usn, s_name
ORDER BY s_usn asc
```

we need the where clause (or a similar one) to ensure we only handle 1 month at a time... if you need a rotating period involving multiple months, a between would work; but your inner php while loop would likely not support that without changes.

[Link for  `extract` usage](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract)

This assumes that a student can only have 1 record for each day in a month in a year.  If multiple records exist, they will be consolidated, as I wouldn't know what that means in terms of usage.

Comment: thank you for reply but can you check my post again i link an image to whatever output i want, sorry cant explain myself and its my first time posting

Comment: @Anonymouse so are you saying this change isn't meeting your need?  it seems to me that it should...

Comment: lets say that those numbers eg. 3,4,7 are legends that serves that the student is present on that date

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do.  I don't understand why my suggestion doesn't work.  If you're trying to get that specific table out of mySQL, you would have to write a 31 case statements 1 for each day of the month possibility and use something like `max(case when at_date=1 then X end as 1), max(case when at_date=2 then X end as 2)... FROM tableName Group by s_usn, s_name`.  The image you have would be the result from SQL.  But your php logic appears like it should already work with a simply order by added; but I don't know if you've tried it or why it's not working.

Comment: can u give me sample sql for the 31 case statements that your talking about ,im closer to understand the logic

Comment: So I've asked about 3 times now if you've simply tried the `order by`.  It seems to me the PHP logic you have would work fine if the result set was just ordered appropriately. As to the 31 case statements `max(case when at_date=1 then 'X' end) as 1`  where at_date would have to be converted to days only. and then you'd need a `group by s_usn, s_name` and an `order by s_usn` or `order by s_name`  X denotes the student had a date matching one of the 31 days of the month.  I think that's the wrong approach though presentation of data should be done in the presentation layer (PHP)

Comment: i tried it but i want the result to be grouped like this one i.stack.imgur.com/fvjyA.png

Comment: and it's not doing that?  perhaps you need an if inside the outer while loop to evaluate if the `s_usn` is different for that record.  if it is write out the html close row and open a new one and set a variable for the oldID to the new ID.  You need two sets of control break logic 1 for the change of IDs, one for the change of days.  the while loop handles the days, where are you handling the IDS?

Comment: this is the result of the first sql you gave me, and by the way my table is in the link also http://imgur.com/a/xagMF

Comment: The PHP is off here now IMO not the SQL (I'm not a PHP guru).  You're missing 1 thing that I can see 1) break out logic for different s_usn's  that ONLY creates a new HTML row when the new .$sql_e_res['s_usn']. is different than the old.  I would think it would be an if statement after the 1st while and before the 2nd that close out a row and opens a new one when the ID's change.  This way you don't get multiple rows

Comment: i cant understand sorry.. >_< can you fix the my code at the top? or atleast add breakpoints, and old and new s_usn

Comment: I can't I'm not good enough with PHP to be able to write something which would help.  At this time I would defer this to someone more familiar with PHP.